# TestCafe conditional if else web element how continue to next condition if first one failed

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

```js
if (btnSubmit.exists) {
    await t
        .click(btnSubmit) //this failed due to button not exist actual is stopped in here
} else if (buttonOK.exists) {
    await t
        .click(buttonOK) //i want to continue to execute this button which is exist
} else {
    console.log("foo")
}
```

I have simple code like this, running automation incase if first condition not found web element then continue next condition but actual is keep failing and stop in first condition.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH63T.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try,

```
    if (await btnSubmit.exists) {
        await t.click(btnSubmit)
    } else if (await buttonOK.exists) {
        await t.click(buttonOK)
    } else {
        console.log("foo")
    }
```

Comment: thanks for suggested @VysakhMohan, just tried its succeed but the action of "t.click" is not execute on front end, any other suggest?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the buttons